# How to display data using hyperlink in php

Tags: php

I already display a list of names in a hyperlink format. When I click on one of the names, it does not display the data related to the name clicked. Can anyone help me..

```
<?php echo '<a href="nama.php?ID='.$rekod['nama'].'">'.$rekod['nama'].'</a>'; ?>
```

this code for student.php page

```
<?php     
   if(isset($_GET[$rekod['nama']]))
                {
                        $id = $_GET[$rekod['nama']];
                    if( $id!= NULL)
                    {
                        $query="SELECT matrik, kp_pass, nama, kod_prog, status
                            FROM _pelajar
                            WHERE nama = '$id'";
                        $qr=mysql_query($query);
        ?>
```

-this code for student.php page

Comment: No code, no help :| ..welcome to SO

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you with so little information. What have you tried? Do you have code to display the data related to the name?

Comment: Help us, help u...show us the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there; you're just looking for the wrong variables:

```
if (isset($_GET['ID'])) {
    $id = $_GET['ID'];                     
    if( $id!= NULL) {
    ....
```

You're passing the variable in as `ID`, so you need to look for that in `$_GET`.